# Reverse a linked list passing the address of a pointer

Tags: c, list, pointers, linked-list, malloc

```
typedef struct slist *LInt;

typedef struct slist{

int value;
LInt next;
}Node;

void reverse(LInt *l){

LInt tail;
if(*l){
    tail=(*l)->next;
    reverse(&tail);
    snoc(&tail,(*l)->value);
    free(*l),
    *l=tail;
    }
}
```

On main, I call the function like this: reverse(&l); (the l is a "LInt l") and what snoc does is to put the value at the last link of the list.

My question is, why do we have to pass the address of "l" when calling the function? And why on the header of reverse, there's "LInt *l"? Is it a pointer to the address I've passed?

I'm sorry if it's a stupid question, and if I made any grammatical errors(English is not my mother language).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Turn on your warnings. `reverse` accepts a `LInt` and you pass it a `LInt*`. Not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1 (why do we have to pass the address of "l" when calling the function?)

The function `reverse()` is suppose to change the original list.  But non-array inputs to a function are `inputs`, they are passed by value.  They do not affect the original `l`.  So to change `l`, you pass its *address* to `reverse()`.  This allows `reverse()` to change `l`, because it knows where `l` exists.

Answer 2 (why on the header of reverse, there's "LInt *l"?)

See answer 1.  `reverse` needs to know the *address* of a type `LInt` in order to affect change.

Example:

```
int x,y;   // 2 non-array variables.
y = f(x);  // X does not change.  You expect y to change.
g(&x);     // After g() is done, the value of x may have changed.
           // Of course, the _address_ of x, being what you passed to g(), did not change.
```

Answer (score 0):

You define the typedef LInt as  POINTER TO STRUCTURE

```
    typedef struct slist *LInt;
```

thats why you don't specify 'next' as LInt next; in structure.

if you would 've defined typedef as

```
    typedef struct slist LInt;
```

then passing the parameter LInt *l is valid. you are passing a structure pointer.

Typedef is to help you to create small UNDERSTANDABLE datatype (synonym not a new one)

consider defining like this :

```
   typedef struct slist LIST;  //i prefer this mostly
   typedef struct slist * LIST_PTR;
```

so when you define new list it doesn't confuse you.

```
   LIST *head;  //creating a pointer - Head of linkedlist
   LIST_PTR head;
```